# applicationContext-common-authorization.xml in spring contacts sample application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, acl

I am quite new to spring framework. For some experiments in my study I want to use spring framework's sample application called contact. I have downloaded the war file from [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/archive-details/org/springframework/security/spring-security-samples-contacts/3.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-samples-contacts-3.0.3.RELEASE.war).

I extracted the war file and in `web-inf/class/` there is a file named `applicationContext-common-authorization.xml` which looks like below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd">

<!--
  - Application context containing the ACL beans.
  -
  -->

  <!-- ========= ACL SERVICE  DEFINITIONS ========= -->

  <bean id="aclCache" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.EhCacheBasedAclCache">
    <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
        <property name="cacheManager">
          <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"/>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheName" value="aclCache"/>
      </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="lookupStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
            <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                    <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                    <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"/>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                    <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ConsoleAuditLogger"/>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="aclService" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="lookupStrategy"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

In this could someone please tell me what does below particular part do ?

```
class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                        <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"/>
                    </bean>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                        <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"/>
                    </bean>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                        <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"/>
                    </bean>
```

1. I was just curious to know if I change the `value=ROLE-SUPERVISOR`, how it will affect the application ?
2. If I want to change permission/role of a user, can I do that by changing parameters here?
3. Basically I am looking for some application in which in configuration file or in xml file if it is web application, one change the role or permission and can try to exploit the application by performing unauthorized access to the application. If someone know such application which is free kindly let me know. It should be in java/jsp only.

I was wondering with spring framework sample application, I can do something like this. But I am not sure whether this is possible with this "contacts" application due to no prior knowledge of spring.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't look like a pure technical question. have you looked at their documentation on how this sample works?

Comment: If you have no prior knowledge of Spring then the contacts sample is a bad place to start as it uses more advanced features. Start with the "tutorial" sample as described in the [manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#sample-apps). There's also a [blog article](http://rwinch.blogspot.com/2011/03/running-spring-securitys-tutorial.html) and screencast which talks you through getting it up and running.

Comment: Luke Taylor is right, Spring Security ACL are an very advanced (and higly under documented) Feature, I you have no need for the ACLs then start with an other tutorial.

Comment: You should also look at Spring Security 3.1, and not 2.0.  There are significant changes that make it much easier to configure now.

Comment: @Luke Taylor Could you please give me a link from which I can download the war file for tutorial. I found for contacts application but not for Tutorial application. Thnaks